# PyGTK: move custom build tooltip window

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygtk

I have built PyGTK application with matplotlib graph in it. I also would like to use custom built tooltip windows. Tooltip value changes according to mouse position on graph.

My problem is that, i can not move my tooltip windows next to my mouse, because i dont know **how to get mouse position in screen**

Here is my stripped code:

```
def figPrepare(self):   #initialize graph
        #figure preparation stuff

        #custom tooltip window
        tooltip = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_POPUP)
        lbl = gtk.Label()
        tooltip.add(lbl)
        lbl.show()

        figure.canvas.set_tooltip_window(tooltip)
        figure.canvas.props.has_tooltip = True
        #events
        figure.canvas.mpl_connect('figure_enter_event',lambda w: tooltip.show())
        figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event',lambda w: self.updateTooltip(tooltip, lbl))
        figure.canvas.mpl_connect('figure_leave_event',lambda w: tooltip.hide())


    def updateTooltip(self, win, lbl):
        lbl.set_text(str(time.time()))
        win.move(w.x, w.y)
```

This code moves tooltip window, but values are based on matplotlib graph, not absolute position in screen.

Could someone point me how to move tooltip windows next to mouse pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

```
def updateTooltip(self, win, lbl):
    lbl.set_text(str(time.time()))
    x, y, mods = win.get_screen().get_root_window().get_pointer()   #this gets absolute mouse possition on screen
    win.move(x+15, y+10)
```